# iptables DROP policies not working with allowed incoming http connection

Tags: networking, iptables, reverse-proxy

I have a task to secure the nginx server, which is working with docker-container as a reverse proxy on port **8732**. I have to disable all incoming connections except port 80 for issuing SSL certificates and, of course, SSH connections. I've set some rules, but they aren't working with INPUT and OUTPUT default policies set to DROP, which is required in the task. The point is, all rules working like a charm with policies set to ACCEPT.
Here's my iptables rules:

```
root@bw:/home/user# iptables -S
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-A INPUT -s <**external address**/24> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d <mail server/32> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-9c6ddba356b8 -o br-9c6ddba356b8 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

here's an output from nmap:

```
    root@bw:/home/user# netstat -tlpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      886/nginx: master p
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      766/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      842/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      886/nginx: master p
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8732            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      49697/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      886/nginx: master p
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      842/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      886/nginx: master p
tcp6       0      0 :::8732                 :::*                    LISTEN      49702/docker-proxy
```

and output from iptables:

```
user@bw:~$ sudo iptables -L -v -n
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 110 packets, 30439 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
11398  751K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       <my subnet address.0/24>       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
33540   15M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 2129  230K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 838 packets, 54784 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 8303 1951K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:22 state ESTABLISHED
33551   15M ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            <mail server ip>         tcp dpt:587 state ESTABLISHED
  176 19390 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:80 state ESTABLISHED

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-9c6ddba356b8 br-9c6ddba356b8  0.0.0.0/0            172.19.0.2           tcp dpt:80
```

Comment: I don't grok what your problem is?

Comment: @vidarlo the point is i have to restrict an internet access to the virtual machine to fully secure it and only allow HTTP. This iptables configuration is working, but only when default policies INPUT and OUTPUT are set to ACCEPT, but I have a task to make it DROP by default, and then add a rule to allow SSH from subnet, and HTTP from the world.

Comment: How do you verify if they work or not?

Comment: @vidarlo, by checking in a web browser the address of the resource. also by CURLing the address, I can't get a 200 response. Probably I mixed up with open ports on network interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Your `OUTPUT` chain is missing the rule to allow established connections from port 80.

Use

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Your `nmap` output is from `netstat`, which is a completely different tool.

The `netstat` output shows which processes have active listening TCP sockets. Whenever you run a daemon that opens a listening socket, it always appears in the list.

Firewall rules operate inside the network stack, and act as a separate isolation layer to access services. When you configure firewall entries, they will restrict traffic to the server. Those rules will have no effect on what `netstat` shows.

You need to check if the rules work by running `iptables -nvL`, which will show counters on how many packets each rule provided. Another check is to make requests to the server from outside and see if the rules work.

Comment: sorry for confusing you, i meant netstat

Comment: i've updated the question with attached output from iptavles

Comment: I updated the answer with a missing rule.

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately, it didn't fixed the problem

Comment: @Taras Paslavskyi post iptables -nvL output again so we can see what you actually done

Comment: @gapsf sure thing, buddy, I have updated my post now

Comment: @Taras Paslavskyi port 80 is now ok it should work. How exectly you check it? Commandline or url you try in browser. Also why you dont check it without any firewall rules just to check it works at all as you expected? I guess firewall is not source of problem

Comment: I’m trying in my browser, which is giving me 504 connection timed out, and in command line with curl, wget. My UFW firewall is disabled, I only using iptables in this case

Comment: @gapsf, it works with iptables input and output policies set to accept. my task is to secure the virtual machine and restrict the internet connection by only allowing HTTP and SSH.
It could be a problem with my reverse-proxy to docker container, which is running on localhost:8732

Comment: To what port you trying to connect from a browser: 80 or 443 or 8732 ? Is it http or https? I need to know exact connection url to figure out this.

Comment: @gapsf i'm trying to connect to port 80, which is giving me 301 and redirects me to https version and after that I'm receiving 504. If I going straight to 443, I'm getting 504 instantly

Comment: If you receive any response, it means that the iptables rules allow the traffic. You need to look at the destination server why it returns HTTP status code 504.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen my nginx reverse proxy looks like this 
location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8732/;
        }
all the matter, with iptables default policies INPUT, OUTPUT to ACCEPT it is working with the rules, and with policies to DROP it is not :)

Comment: @Taras Paslavskyi
Obviously you should open 443/tcp port as well

Comment: @gapsf, thanks for getting back to me. this port is opened https://imgur.com/OQ6dYiT

Comment: @Taras Paslavskyi No, 443 port is closed by firewall - it's not allowed in INPUT and dropped according the DROP policy. Your screenshot is about listening sockets, not about firewalling. I'v post the answer for current situation

Answer (score 0):

> I have to disable all incoming connections except port 80 for issuing
> SSL certificates and, of course, SSH connections

> i'm trying to connect to port 80, which is giving me 301 and
> redirects me to https version and after that I'm receiving 504. If I
> going straight to 443, I'm getting 504 instantly

By default - HTTP is 80/tcp, HTTPS is 443/tcp. You have 80/tcp opened only.

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Also notice, in OUTPUT you do not allow any NEW connection (so effectively block all NEW)   **from** the host. So for example DNS queries blocked or maybe something else impotent for your host functioning.
Also you don't need repeat rules in OUTPUT for each corresponding INPUT rule.
**Better organize rules in INPUT and OUTPUT in cleaner, predictable and secure way like this pattern**

```
-P MAIN_CHAIN DROP
-A MAIN_CHAIN -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A MAIN_CHAIN -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# next rules ACCEPT only NEW for all your needs
-A MAIN_CHAIN -m state --state NEW match-something1 -j ACCEPT
-A MAIN_CHAIN -m state --state NEW match-something2 -j ACCEPT
#... and so on
```

So your rules would be:

```
-P INPUT DROP
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -s <**external address**/24> --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

-P OUTPUT DROP
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i've noticed there should be A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT instead of -o in that line and dash before the "m" here -A INPUT m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT and here -A OUTPUT m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j and in the end should be added ACCEPT after -j

Comment: besides that, unfortunately it does not help me, with allowed 80 and 443 and INPUT DROP it still not opening and I can't ping on that port
root@bw:/home/user# ping localhost:8732
 Name or service not known

Comment: Update answer. You can't ping tcp/udp port only IP, ping use icmp protocol and should be accepted

Comment: thanks for pointing this, i'm absolute noob in networking. Is there any ways to troubleshoot why nginx cant serve docker-container ? it's working as reverse proxy

Comment: What commandline you use tu run your docker container? Read "Public Networking" here https://earthly.dev/blog/docker-networking/ Until that i guess from your `netstat -tlpn` output you map docker's 80 port to 8732 so you should open tcp 8732 in INPUT and connect from browser on 8732 or if you want standard 80 you should map port 80 of container to port 80 of host in `docker run` command. Also check what iptables rules looks like after docker run - docker may change it for you

Comment: im running it with "docker-compose up -d", the docker-compose file has the following port mapping: 
ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8732:80"
and In nginx:
location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8732/;

Comment: root@bw:/opt/vault# docker ps
PORTS 3012/tcp, 127.0.0.1:8732->80/tcp

Comment: Ok, nginx listen on host's 80 and proxy it to container on 127.0.0.1:8732. Should work. What nginx logs says about connections? Can you connect to 127.0.0.1:8732 from a browser from you host?

Comment: Also you use SSL when try to connecting from outside? What is you full configuration of nginx server{} block? Are you opened 443 in INPUT? nginx listen on 443? Provide actual information and configuration for iptables and nginx and full urls you connect in a browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138803/discussion-between-taras-paslavskyi-and-gapsf).

Comment: hello there, i've provided more info In chat as you've requested, cheers